# SQL coalesce Null columns

Tags: sql, coalesce

```
select 
    id
 , coalesce(iff(name = 'Alpha', price, null), null) alpha_price
 ,null as beta_price
 , coalesce(iff(name = 'beta', price, null), null) beta_price
  from table1
```

Input table :

```
ID     name     price
123   alpha      29
123   beta       40
```

output :

```
id.     alpha_price     beta_price 
123       29             NULL
123       NULL           40
```

expected output :

```
id     alpha_price     beta_price 
123       29             40
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  `IIF()` is not a standard SQL function.  And why would you use `coalesce()` with two arguments with the second argument being `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to aggregate here:

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(alpha_price) AS alpha_price, MAX(beta_price) AS beta_price
FROM table1
GROUP BY id;
```

This works, at least on the sample data you did show, because the `MAX` function will by default ignore `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregates (case expressions inside aggregate functions) direct from the input table should go straight to the desired result:

```
SELECT
      id
    , MAX(case when name = 'alpha' then price end) AS alpha_price
    , MAX(case when name = 'beta' then price end) AS beta_price
FROM input_table
GROUP BY id
```